# How to Choose R Server's R as Default in Operationalization, Remote R Workspace and RStudio Server?

Tags: r, linux, azure

So I've set up an Azure Data Science Virtual Machine on Linux (Ubuntu) and I've executed the following on the terminal to enable Remote R workspace, RStudio Server, R Server Operationalization and hadoop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade

# Hadoop is installed but doesn't seem to appear on the PATH or have its environment variable set by default
sudo echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
sudo echo "export PATH="'$'"PATH:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
sudo echo "export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4" >> ~/.bashrc
#
source ~/.bashrc

#Setting up a password as none exists to begin with because of private key selection in the installation
#RStudio Server requires a password though
"MyPassword\nMyPassword\n" | sudo passwd sshuser

#Unfortunately hadoop fails on Data Science Virtual Machine
#error: mkdir: Call From IM-DSonUbuntu/192.168.5.4 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
# hadoop fs -mkdir /user/RevoShare/rserve2
# hadoop fs -chmod uog+rwx /user/RevoShare/rserve2
sudo mkdir -p /var/RevoShare/rserve2
sudo chmod uog+rwx /var/RevoShare/rserve2
# hadoop fs -mkdir /user/RevoShare/sshuser
# hadoop fs -chmod uog+rwx /user/RevoShare/sshuser
sudo mkdir -p /var/RevoShare/sshuser
sudo chmod uog+rwx /var/RevoShare/sshuser

#Setting up R Server Operationalisation
cd /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/o16n
sudo dotnet Microsoft.MLServer.Utils.AdminUtil/Microsoft.MLServer.Utils.AdminUtil.dll -silentoneboxinstall MyPassword


#They say this Data Science Virtual Machine already has RStudio Server, but even though the port 8787 is open, it's nowhere to be found! So installing it now, and after the installation it's accessible by refreshing the page that failed before.
#Perhaps it's not installed then? Or a service is not running like it shoudl?
#https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.414-amd64.deb
yes | sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.414-amd64.deb
#They are small, leave them for debug reasons - lets have evidence the script run thus far.
#sudo rm rstudio-server-1.1.414-amd64.deb

# Remote R workspace Service needs dotnet sdk
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
sudo apt install libxml2-dev

#Downloading and installing the Remote R service
wget -O rtvs-daemon.tar.gz https://aka.ms/r-remote-services-linux-binary-current
tar -xvzf rtvs-daemon.tar.gz
sudo ./rtvs-install -s
sudo systemctl enable rtvsd
sudo systemctl start rtvsd
#sudo rm rtvs-daemon.tar.gz
#sudo rm rtvs-install

#Fixing Remote R: For some reason, even though 'sudo systemctl enable rtvsd' runs, after every reboot the service won't become automatically active. So let's fix that.
wget https://sa0im0general.blob.core.windows.net/general-blob-container/StartRemoteRAfterReboot.sh
sudo mv StartRemoteRAfterReboot.sh /var/RevoShare/StartRemoteRAfterReboot.sh

sudo /sbin/shutdown -r 5

sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
sudo -s
sudo find /etc/ -name "rc.local" -exec sed -i 's/exit 0//g' {} \;
sudo echo "" >> /etc/rc.local
sudo echo "sh /var/RevoShare/StartRemoteRAfterReboot.sh" >> /etc/rc.local
sudo echo "exit 0" >> /etc/rc.local
exit
```

I've also tried, one by one, these, to see if it makes any difference to the RStudio Server (it didn't, but even if it did, I want a global solution to work on Remote R Workspace Service and R Server Operationalisation as well, not only RStudio Server):

```
#Configuring RStudio Server to see the R Server R
sudo echo "rsession-which-r=/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R/R" >> /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf

export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R/R
sudo echo "RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R/R" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
sudo echo "RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R/R" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

sudo echo "PATH=$PATH:/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R" >> ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/bin/R
source ~/.bashrc
```

The problem is that even though "which R" points to R Server's R, i.e. typing "sudo R" will show the message "Loading Microsoft R Server packages, version 9.2.1." and will load packages like RevoScaleR, everything else fails to do so.

1. Accessing the RStudio Server with http://THE-IP-GOES-HERE.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8787 and logging in with the initial user ("sshuser") (or with any other user for that matter) will NOT load R Server and RevoScaleR rx functions are unavailable
2. Using my local Visual Studio 2017 to access the remote workspace via "Add connection" on "Workspaces" tab loads MRO and says:

> Installed R versions:

```
    [0] Microsoft R Open '3.4.1.1347' (Default)
```

3. And finally, when I use R Server's Operationalisation and log in with "mrsdeploy" package's "remoteLogin()" R Server packages like RevoScaleR are not loaded again, so things like "rxSummary(~., data=iris)" fail with error 'could not find function "rxSummary"'

The exact same thing happened when I deployed from azure a "Machine Learning Server 9.2.1 on Linux (Ubuntu)".

I don't want to just use the regular open source R, I want to be able to use the R Server - that's why I deployed this VM. How can I make it so that everything loads R Server's R, not Microsoft R Open? (Like I'm able to do from terminal using "R")

As a result of my having tried all of this and the fact that R Server is loaded in the console, my mind now goes to permissions. Could it be that by default the Data Science VM doesn't have the correct permissions to allow these?
I'm at a loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio Server is installed on the Ubuntu DSVM, but the service is disabled by default as it does not support SSL. You can enable it with *systemctl enable rstudio-server*, then start it with *systemctl start rstudio-server*.

RStudio Server uses the same R as Microsoft R Server, but the .libPaths are different, which is why you cannot load the MRS packages. You will need to manually set the .libPaths so they match.

Comment: I see, thank you for the information. Could you please give an example of how to set the .libPaths in such a way as to not disrupt anything, but add the ability to load MRS packages?

Comment: Nevermind, for both Azure DSVM and MLS VM, the answer is: `.libPaths(c("/data/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer", .libPaths()))`. Thank you very much for the information!! I've marked it as the answered and gave +1